# Given X and Y as a couple random variables, what is alpha

Tags: probability

[image]

If we are given this problem, how to determine $P(X=1, Y=0)$? The correct answer is $0$ as outlined, but I don't know how it was deduced.

Comment: It is $1-(\frac 1  8+\frac 5 {24})=\frac 2 3$

Comment: It s incorrect, the original one has it =$0$ In the textbook I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it as $1-P((X=1,Y=0)^{C})$, where $C$ denotes the complementary of the event $(X=1,Y=0)$. Now, $P((X=1,Y=0)^{C})$ is just the sum of all the probabilities appearing in the table, and they add up to 1, so $P(X=1,Y=0)=1-P((X=1,Y=0)^{C})=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of all joint probabilites in the table should be $1$. Since you are given all probabilities except for that of $X=1, Y=0$, find the answer as follows:

$P(X=1, Y=0) = 1 - \Big( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{5}{24} \Big) = 1 - 1 = 0$.